# Why didn't Brienne of Tarth give the wolf bread to Arya Stark?

Tags: game-of-thrones

The baker kid gave Brienne of Tarth a bread shaped like a wolf/fox. When Brienne met Arya Stark, why didn't she give her the bread? It might have helped convince her to go with her. I'm referring to the TV show.

Comment: She was busy having a bit of a tiff with The Hound.

Comment: Maybe she already ate it?

Comment: Hotpie made you a breads! [But I eated it :(](http://cutecaptions.com/images/i-no-do-it/i-made-you-a-cupcake-but-i-eated-i.jpg)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think there was quite some time in between those two events, and I think the bread would have spoilt during that period.

Comment: This sounds more like an opinion than an answer. Do you have any supporting evidence of how long it was before Brienne met up with Arya?

Comment: I don't, at least not yet since I don't have the time to look it up at this moment. But at the moment of Arya meeting Brienne, Arya had already traveled to the Eyrie and the Twins. This seems like quite the long journey for bread to stay edible. At least if bread has roughly the same characteristics as bread in real life, it would spoil within a matter of days if it's not frozen. It's more a matter of logic rather than opinion, this however is my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

The basic answer is, there just wasn't time. Putting aside the question of whether the bread would even still be edible after an unknown time on the road, their actual interaction was too brief before Brienne and The Hound came to blows.

In a matter of moments, we have Brienne encountering Arya as a stranger on the road, determine that it is Arya, make her pledge of protection (which would certainly be more important in her mind than the bread), be refused by The Hound, and draw her sword.

Once The Hound has been defeated, Arya has hidden herself away leaving Brienne without any further opportunity to offer the bread or make any other moves toward gaining her trust.